# How to get iframe contents height when src is base64 encoded?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, base64, height

Here is the iframe I want to show the contents dynamically.

```
<iframe onload='resize()' id='ifr' src='data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,Encoded text here' width=100% height=400px></iframe>
```

I tried something like this.. but the height always return 0

```
function resize() {
   $('#ifr').height($('#ifr').contents().height());
}
```

Here is jsfiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/zetapark/rajz6sy5/1/

Comment: Can you create a runnable demo somewhere like jsfiddle, plunker, codepen etc? Or even in a stacksnippet by clicking on `<>` in question editor

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zetapark/rajz6sy5/1/

Comment: I made a jsfiddle ...it was undefined.. not 0..

Comment: OK is as I suspected. Can't access it due to same origin policy. https://jsfiddle.net/t7fk1364/ Could try setting `document.domain = 'yourPageDomain'` in script tag inside the iframe

Comment: Not working....

Comment: Right...look at the security warning in console telling you you can't access a cross origin object

Answer (score -1):

$('iframe') gives you all the iframe in your document, so either you should give id to your frame and use it like $('#MYiframe') or get the first element from what jquert returns.

```
function resize() {
   $('iframe')[0].height($('iframe')[0].contents().height());
}
```

and I have also found on SO this for resizing the iframe for contents.

```
iFrame.width  = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
```